# How can i add a delete button to delete token

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, token, tokenize

I am trying to create a control where it will accept tag kind of functionality in which we use in stackoverflow. I am trying to customize RichTextBox to achieve this functionality. I have refer the below link as reference.

http://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens/

How can i add a delete button to delete token?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the above functionality by adding a Button to the DataTemplate. Then assigning the InLineUIContainer to the Tag proeprty of the button. Then on the button click event you can remove the InLineUIContainer from the RichTextBox.
Refer the below code for the modified DataTemplate and the Tokenizer Control code.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TokenizingControlTester" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="TokenizingControlTester.MainWindow"
    Title="Testing TokenizingControl" Height="244" Width="525" Icon="14-tag.png">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NameTokenTemplate">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded1">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="#FF7E7E7E" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Height="Auto" d:DesignWidth="139" d:DesignHeight="40" Padding="5,3" Margin="3,0,3,3">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD0A0" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFAB5600" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.21*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.79*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.79*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right" Source="14-tag.png" Stretch="None" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Button Name="btnClose" Content="X" Grid.Column="2"  />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnLoaded1}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <DockPanel.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFB8CCF7" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF313131" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </DockPanel.Background>

    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="5,5,5,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.059*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.941*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="08-chat.png" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>

        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter any text ending with semi-colon &quot;;&quot; and have it immediately converted to a Token" FontSize="16" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Grid.Column="1" Margin="7,0,0,0"/>

    </Grid>

    <local:TokenizingControl x:Name="Tokenizer"  IsDocumentEnabled="True"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,11,5,0" TokenTemplate="{DynamicResource NameTokenTemplate}" FontSize="16" MinHeight="40" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph><Run /></Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </local:TokenizingControl>

</DockPanel>
```

```
 public class TokenizingControl : RichTextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TokenTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TokenTemplate", typeof (DataTemplate), typeof (TokenizingControl));

    public DataTemplate TokenTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate) GetValue(TokenTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TokenTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public Func<string, object> TokenMatcher { get; set; }

    public TokenizingControl()
    {
        TextChanged += OnTokenTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnTokenTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var text = CaretPosition.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Backward);
        if (TokenMatcher != null)
        {
            var token = TokenMatcher(text);
            if (token != null)
            {
                ReplaceTextWithToken(text, token);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReplaceTextWithToken(string inputText, object token)
    {
        // Remove the handler temporarily as we will be modifying tokens below, causing more TextChanged events
        TextChanged -= OnTokenTextChanged;

        var para = CaretPosition.Paragraph;

        var matchedRun = para.Inlines.FirstOrDefault(inline =>
        {
            var run = inline as Run;
            return (run != null && run.Text.EndsWith(inputText));
        }) as Run;
        if (matchedRun != null) // Found a Run that matched the inputText
        {
            var tokenContainer = CreateTokenContainer(inputText, token);
            para.Inlines.InsertBefore(matchedRun, tokenContainer);


            // Remove only if the Text in the Run is the same as inputText, else split up
            if (matchedRun.Text == inputText)
            {
                para.Inlines.Remove(matchedRun);
            }
            else // Split up
            {
                var index = matchedRun.Text.IndexOf(inputText) + inputText.Length;
                var tailEnd = new Run(matchedRun.Text.Substring(index));
                para.Inlines.InsertAfter(matchedRun, tailEnd);
                para.Inlines.Remove(matchedRun);
            }
        }

        TextChanged += OnTokenTextChanged;
    }

    private Dictionary<int, object> dic = new Dictionary<int, object>();

    private InlineUIContainer CreateTokenContainer(string inputText, object token)
    {
        // Note: we are not using the inputText here, but could be used in future

        var presenter = new ContentPresenter()
        {              

            Content = token,
            ContentTemplate = TokenTemplate,
        };
        presenter.ApplyTemplate();
        Button bt = TokenTemplate.FindName("btnClose", presenter) as Button;
        bt.Click += bt_Click;

        InlineUIContainer inlin=  new InlineUIContainer(presenter) { BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.TextBottom };
        bt.Tag = inlin;
        // BaselineAlignment is needed to align with Run
       return inlin;
    }

    void bt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        InlineUIContainer inputText = btn.Tag as InlineUIContainer;
        Paragraph pr = null;
        foreach (var block in this.Document.Blocks)
        {
            if (block is Paragraph)
            {
                var paragraph = block as Paragraph;

                if(paragraph.Inlines.Contains(inputText))
                {
                    pr = paragraph;
                }
            }
        }
        pr.Inlines.Remove(inputText);           
    }
}
```